# SQL Periodic table updates

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Morning all

I wish to create a table which essentially acts like a view but only updates once a week. Not sure how to start this process...looking at scheduled tasks.

I was thinking essentially it would be a clearing function which clears the table at the start of the week and re-runs the initial SQL command to populate...But unsure and need some advice please.

The reason I am looking at doing a table rather than a view is so I can set up periodically to update tables to create / show trends analysis over time

Thanks in advance

Comment: do it using sql server jobs

Comment: Agree with @bmsqldev.  Take a look at the Microsoft docs for creating a [SQL Agent job](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187901.aspx).

Comment: Thanks will take a look

Answer (score 0):

You may also look at using SSIS package and then schedule this as a task